# What maven plugin should be used for generating karaf features.xml?

Tags: maven, karaf

google tells me about a couple of different plugins. features-maven-plugin, karaf-maven-plugin. I am not sure which of these should be used and what versions. Is this dependent on the karaf version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

features-maven-plugin is deprecated in version >= 3.X as you can see in several Karaf documentation [Karaf Doc 3.X](http://apache.crihan.fr/dist/karaf/documentation/3_x.pdf) and [Karaf Doc 4.X](http://apache.crihan.fr/dist/karaf/documentation/4_x.pdf) .

So if you used a Karaf >= 3.X you must used karaf-maven-plugin .

Comment: thanks. It does seem that way. I am still running into issues with maven not being able to recognize the goal... Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging features-generate-descriptor